# How to prevent Ubuntu 16.04 from freezing after login ( nvidia graphic card and uefi secureboot)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uefi

I've been using Ubuntu for a year now without any major issue so I decided last month to install it onto my desktop.

It worked well for a month and then, on morning, It just stopped working.

Once I log in, it freezes. I searched on the internet and came to the conclusion that the problem was linked to my graphics card (nvidia) and secure boot. I managed to turn off secure boot and to install the new driver onto my computer and it worked again.

Then, I plugged a wifi dongle in, and it froze again.

I reinstalled Ubuntu.

On the first boot, I installed the nvidia drivers and started to reupload all my stuff onto it.

On the second boot... it froze again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post the hardware specs, namely the graphics card model (and the WiFi's) and also what drivers ersion have you installed and *how*.

Comment: Secure Boot doesn't allow you to use certain "non free" components. In my case for example I have issues with my Ethernet realtek controller and my Atheros WiFi... I would say that you'd better install your ubutnu again without secure boot which at the end of day offers security for windows more than anything else. You can boot your windows in secure mode anyway. Did you actualized all your system before installing nvida drivers? As celtic warrior suggested we need more data about your hardware and configuration.

Comment: tbh, I think the problem is solved, now, it was because of secureboot, all that you say make sense. what do you mean by "actualizing all your system before installing nvidia drivers" though ?